# Windows 10 falsely displays that wifi has limited access

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking

I have two laptops that have full working internet access, but the icon displays as limited access. If I manually go to http://www.msftconnecttest.com/connecttest.txt the laptop immediately sees that the network is not limited and fixes the icon, but then forgets again 30-60 minutes later. The connection still works and displays as working even if I reboot right away, it seems to be a time thing.

In addition, the laptop will not automatically connect to wifi, it says action needed, but when I click connect, it opens Edge and works fine, just with a limited Icon on the Wifi until I go to the above website.

Any idea what is going on with this?

Comment: Try forgetting the wifi connection and connect to it manually checking the automatically connect. Also make sure the time on your computer is synced with a timeserver. Time being off can cause for weird problems.

Comment: The time is right, forgetting the network did not help. I ended up enabling the Turn off Windows Network Connectivity Status Indicator active tests GPO to make this go away.